# Open file with fopen in metro app

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-8

I try too open file

```
const char *path = "C:/1/123.somebinaryfile";
FILE *f = fopen(path, "rb");
```

But i have error "Unable to read from file".

How i can fix it? May be i must add some declaration in manifest? Or metro apps have permission only for library?

Comment: are you sure a .txt can read from binary? i thought you needed a .bin for binary reading/writing

Comment: txt is example. In my program i use other format.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the same restrictions that apply to [CreateFile2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) do apply to fopen as well:

> When called from a Windows Store app, CreateFile2 is simplified. Only files or directories inside the ApplicationData.LocalFolder or Package.InstalledLocation directories or may be opened. Opening named pipes or mailslots or creating encrypted files (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED) are also not supported.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have comes from the fact that Modern UI apps, are not allowed access to the filesystem, unless the user have selected the file with a file picker, or such file is part of the app's package.

Comment: Ok, i open this file with FilePicker, can i use fopen?

Comment: Yeah, sure, if want a quick look you can check the Microsoft provided sample here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba

Comment: Afaik you can only access files inside your application local storage using POSIX API. Everything outside of that, you'll have to use (I)StorageFile and the new WinRT API.
The reason for that is that Microsoft wants to phase out the whole filesystem concept: an IStorageFile may lie on a remote device, may be a totally virtual concept and got nothing to do with C:\What\Have\You.dat

Comment: @Rafael Those examples don't show fopen. They still use the IStorageFile stuff.